# Are "switching circuit" and "circuit switching" related?

Tags: circuit-design, communication, switching, network

"[Switching circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_circuit_theory)"  is a concept opposed to [logic circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Electronic_gates). Both are used for implementing digital circuits.

The first link says

> From 1934 to 1936, NEC engineer Akira Nakashima published a series of papers showing that the two-valued Boolean algebra, which he discovered independently, can describe the operation of **switching circuits**.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching)[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_circuit_theory) His work was later cited and elaborated on in Claude Shannon's seminal 1938 paper "A Symbolic Analysis of **Relay and Switching Circuits**".[4] The principles of Boolean algebra are applied to switches, providing mathematical tools for analysis and synthesis of **any switching system**.

The second link says

> **Electronic logic gates** differ significantly from their **relay-and-switch equivalents**. They are much faster, consume much less power, and are much smaller (all by a factor of a million or more in most cases). Also, there is a fundamental structural difference. **The switch circuit** creates a continuous metallic path for current to flow (in either direction) between its input and its output. **The semiconductor logic gate**, on the other hand, acts as a high-gain voltage amplifier, which sinks a tiny current at its input and produces a low-impedance voltage at its output. It is not possible for current to flow between the output and the input of a semiconductor logic gate.

"[Circuit switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching)" is a concept opposed to packet switching. Both are used in telecommunication and computer networks.

Are the two groups of concepts related?

- Are "switching circuit" and "circuit switching" related?
- Are "logic circuit" and "packet switching" related?

Is switching circuit  used for digital circuits, not analog circuits?

Is switching circuit  replaced by logic circuits, or does it have usages that is not replaceable by logic circuits?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Switching circuit" is a concept opposed to logic circuits.* Huh, no. Any circuit that expresses a type of logic is a logic circuit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Electronic_gates, and ch4 in Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Boolean Algebra and Switching Circuits by Elliott Mendelson (1970)

Comment: what does that have to do with it, at all? All these gates are logic circuits, subject to switching circuit theory.

Comment: Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Boolean Algebra and Switching Circuits by Elliott Mendelson (1970) has a chapter " Chapter 4 Switching circuits and logic circuits"

Comment: yes, logic circuit is the broader term, it also applies to non-binary logic, for example. Do you have a specific question about that book?

Comment: My specific question are in my post.

Comment: so, why are you quoting a chapter title from the book then?

Comment: Because I can't copy the whole book in a comment.

Comment: let me rephrase: "if your question is unrelated to the book, why do mention it?"

Comment: Because I don't know if you mean the same thing by "switching circuit" and "logic circuit" as the book and wikipedia do.

Comment: huh? If you have a specific question about my answer, please ask that specific question as a comment to my answer, thanks!

Comment: "switch circuit" means an electronic circuit based on switches (relays). Nothing more, nothing less

Answer (score 4):

> "Switching circuit" is a concept opposed to logic circuits.

No.

"Switching circuit theory" is in the end nothing but a term for "binary logic circuit theory". It's a term from the beginning of the computer era, and although rarely used today, describes basically any logic circuit you'll find today – from simple AND gates to a complete computer including CPU, RAM, GPU ...

> "Circuit switching" is a concept opposed to packet switching.

Yeah, that's kind of true – when we say "circuit switching", we mean that a dedicated connection for the duration of communication is made between two parties. Packet switching implies that for every data packet, the routing decision is made more or less independently of a "connection".

> Are "switching circuit" and "circuit switching" related?

Made of the same word. Other than that, no.

For example, the classical circuit switching is rooms full of *operators* taking a cable to connect two telephone lines, so that people could talk. (telephony before 1950)

That has nothing to do with what switching circuit theory is about (i.e. logic statements to be made by analyzing a circuit).

> Are "logic circuit" and "packet switching" related?

You'll need a logic circuit (for example, a network card and a CPU) to do packet switching.

Other than that, no.

> Is switching circuit used for digital circuits, not analog circuits?

err, basically "switching circuit theory" is what you'd call "digital circuit theory" these days.

> Is switching circuit replaced by logic circuits, or does it have usages that is not replaceable by logic circuits?

This question makes no sense, see above.

Comment: the post office does packet switching, historically they managed this without digital logic :^)

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading about George Peacock, and his work on algebra and logic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Peacock